# C# cascading assignment

Tags: c#, performance-testing, assignment-operator

Is there is any performance degrades when we assign values like this?

```
Dropdown1.Enable = dropdown2.Enable = dropdown3.Enable = false;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: don't know why this question is marked as too localized. it's fairly practical and NOT 'localized' IMO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is that there is no impact - it is equivalent to three assignment statements.

There are not even any `get` operations called, as is proven below:

Console application project:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace ConsoleApplication5
{
    public class X

    {
        private int _a;
        private int _b;

        public int A
        {
            get
            {
                Console.WriteLine("get A");
                return _a + 1;
            }
            set
            {
                Console.WriteLine("set A");
                _a = value;
            }
        }

        public int B
        {
            get
            {
                Console.WriteLine("get B");
                return _b + 2;
            }
            set
            {
                Console.WriteLine("set B");
                _b = value;
            }
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var x = new X();

            Console.WriteLine("Assign");
            int y = x.B = x.A = 125;

            Console.WriteLine("Read");
            Console.WriteLine("y " + y + " x.B " + x.B + " x.A " + x.A);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Generates:

```
Assign
set A
set B
Read
get B
get A
y 125 x.B 127 x.A 126
```

Note that during the assign phase, no 'get'ers are called, and even though the getters of A and B return different values than the value set on them, the value ultimately assigned to `y` is the source value on the RHS of the expression.

Comment: just checked and didn't see this behavior documented c# spec. i wonder is it?

Answer (score 1):

I may be misunderstanding something from the other two answers, but I don't think any `getters` are being fired. In all three cases, it's the *setter* that's fired for the properties. Furthermore, I'm pretty sure the IL just pushes the `false` value onto the stack three times and fires the setter once for each.

For the following class:

```
public class Test
{
    public bool Prop { get; set; }
}
```

For `t1.Prop = t2.Prop = t3.Prop = false;` the IL is:

```
IL_0013:  ldloc.0     //t1
IL_0014:  ldloc.1     //t2
IL_0015:  ldloc.2     //t2
IL_0016:  ldc.i4.0    //false
IL_0017:  dup         //dup the false on the stack
IL_0018:  stloc.3     
IL_0019:  callvirt    UserQuery+Test.set_Prop //set value
IL_001E:  nop         
IL_001F:  ldloc.3     
IL_0020:  dup         //dup the false on the stack
IL_0021:  stloc.3     
IL_0022:  callvirt    UserQuery+Test.set_Prop //set value
IL_0027:  nop         
IL_0028:  ldloc.3     
IL_0029:  callvirt    UserQuery+Test.set_Prop //set value
```

For:

```
t1.Prop = false;
t2.Prop = false;
t3.Prop = false;
```

The IL is:

```
IL_0012:  stloc.2     
IL_0013:  ldloc.0     
IL_0014:  ldc.i4.0    //false  
IL_0015:  callvirt    UserQuery+Test.set_Prop //set value
IL_001A:  nop         
IL_001B:  ldloc.1     
IL_001C:  ldc.i4.0    //false
IL_001D:  callvirt    UserQuery+Test.set_Prop //set value
IL_0022:  nop         
IL_0023:  ldloc.2     
IL_0024:  ldc.i4.0    //false 
IL_0025:  callvirt    UserQuery+Test.set_Prop //set value
```

So the IL is pretty close and really the only difference is hitting `ldc.i4.0` three times, or hitting it once and duplicating it on the stack twice. Performance is inconsequential. IF however obtaining that `false` value was a non-trivial operation, it would take longer putting it on three lines, but you could just as easily write:

```
bool value = SomeLongOperation();
t1.Prop = value;
t2.Prop = value;
t3.Prop = value;
```

So do whatever is best for readability and/or your standards within your company.

EDIT: Actually, I wouldn't be surprised if the compiler/JIT would optimize the separate line entry to essentially the first case (or whichever is faster) or to some other optimized state. Really, the only thing to be concerned about is the last code sample; if you need to do `SomeLongOperation()` to get the value, only do it once. After that, do whatever is readable.

Answer (score 0):

You would usualy do it like this:

```
variable1 = varaible2 = variable3 = 123
```

But since the `Enable` property is a getter, it is not possible.
Internally, a getter looks like this:

```
public bool Enabled
{
    get
    {
        return something;
    }
    set
    {
        something = value;
    }
}
```